# Is there a way to detect keypresses on python in ubuntu without having to run my program as root?

Tags: python, ubuntu, keypress, ubuntu-20.04

A python program I'm working requires keypress detection. The keyboard library in python requires the program to be run as root. Is there any other library that doesn't require running the program as root in Ubuntu?

Comment: Normally, programs that “require keypress detection” just read from stdin. What’s your exact need here?

Comment: I'm working on a text-animation player for the terminal. I need keypresses for functions like pausing and playing

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, I don't think you've got any good options here. Keyboard events in a console aren't exposed to the process except through stdin. You can turn off line buffering, but that's about it.  You can do it in a graphical application through Xlib, of course, just not as a process running in a terminal.

Comment: Though actually, rereading again, I'm not sure if you need the raw events. If you need keydown and keyup events, then my previous comment stands: you need Xlib or root. If you're just looking to be notified when a key is typed -- rather than that being buffered until the user hits enter -- then you want [ncurses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).